# Linux Huge Pages and child termination by SIGBUS after fork()

Tags: c, linux, fork, huge-pages

In Linux, access to hugepages is provided through a virtual file
system *hugetlbfs*.  The *libhugetlbfs* library interface works with
*hugetlbfs* to provide more convenient specific application-level
services.

*libhugetlbfs* can be used to make an existing application use hugepages
for all its *malloc()* calls.

To run a program using the automatic hugepage *malloc()* feature, I have set following environment variables:

1. Set *LD_PRELOAD=libhugetlbfs.so*
2. Set *LD_LIBRARY_PATH* to the directory containing *libhugetlbfs.so*
3. Set *HUGETLB_MORECORE=yes*

Now, my new process uses huge pages, if available, for all *malloc()* memory. But when it executes *fork()* system call and if there are not enough huge pages on the system, the child gets terminated by **SIGBUS**. This is happening because when child tries to update some memory location in the malloc'd memory, page fault occurs. Due to Copy-On-Write mechanism, system tries to allocate new huge page to child to serve the page fault. But since there is no huge page available, kernel generates the **SIGBUS** and errors out.

I would appreciate any help/pointer to work around the ugly termination of child by **SIGBUS** and causing core.

Comment: The memory is available but the huge pages are not available. I expect in the absence of huge pages regular sized memory pages should be used. Please let me know Which part of the question is unclear. I will try to restate it.

Comment: Ok, so to restate the problem: A program allocates hugepages and then forks.  When the child starts to modify pages, it runs out of space because the system is unable to allocate a new hugepage and does not instead create pages from regular memory.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for summing up.